# Symfony 5 and Docker : missing RABBITMQ_DSN env var

Tags: php, docker, symfony, rabbitmq, environment-variables

I've just setup a RabbitMQ Docker container to use with a Symfony 5.2 application. But I'm having troubles with auto-exposed env vars from Docker.

As the RabbitMQ container is up and running fine, I'm waiting for a `RABBITMQ_DSN` env var automatically set by Symfony.

The weird behaviour is sometimes I do get this env var but sometimes I don't (on the same request !).

I also get the same behaviour when dumping my env vars (I sware there are no changes between the 2 commands...) :

```
$ APP_ENV=dev symfony var:export --multiline | grep 'RABBITMQ'
export RABBITMQ_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:49167
export RABBITMQ_HOST=127.0.0.1
export RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_HOST=127.0.0.1
export RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_IP=127.0.0.1
export RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_PORT=49168
export RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SCHEME=http
export RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SERVER=http://127.0.0.1:49168
export RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_URL=http://127.0.0.1:49168
export RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest
export RABBITMQ_PORT=49167
export RABBITMQ_SCHEME=amqp
export RABBITMQ_SERVER=amqp://127.0.0.1:49167
export RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:49167
export RABBITMQ_USER=guest
export RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest

$ APP_ENV=dev symfony var:export --multiline | grep 'RABBITMQ'
export RABBITMQ_HOST=127.0.0.1
export RABBITMQ_IP=127.0.0.1
export RABBITMQ_PORT=49168
```

I' tried several things :

- update Docker RabbitMQ image from 3.7 to 3.8
- clear Symfony cache
- with auto and manual port mapping (in docker-compose.yaml)
- updated all my dependencies

But I'm still stuck with this bug... I'm running this app on Windows 10.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok,
I found a workaround by using another env var that I setup explicitly in my `.env` file.

I can't figure out why this `RABBITMQ_DSN` env var is sometimes missing.

Here is the workaround.

Just set up a new env var in `.env` file :

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:49167
```

And use it instead of the missing `RABBITMQ_DSN` in your `messenger.yml` file :

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
```

Comment: Could you tell what your workaround is? In the project I'm working at we have the same issue.